# Measurements in Photoshop do not match 100% print view size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using Photoshop CC. My problem is occurs when I create a new file. If I make it with 15cm width and 10cm height (i.e A6 size), when I view it in 100% (i.e print size) the result on my screen is smaller than the paper I'm using. When I compare my school ruler against the Photoshop ruler, units on the Photoshop ruler shows appear to be smaller.

I have not printed it yet, only made it in Photoshop, but when I choose to print it ( Ctrl + P ) it looks like it should be the right size.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate your screen's DPI here: http://dpi.lv/

Enter the results in Photoshop Settings/Preferences under `Units & Rulers > Screen Resolution`.

Comment: Thank you guys, it actually work. When i choose "print size" option it fit to my paper. But the zoom size is 33,33%.

When i zoom to 100%, it larger than my screen. What is that mean?

Comment: You should do some reading on DPI. 

http://www.vsellis.com/understanding-dpi-resolution-and-print-vs-web-images/ 

This should be expected. Your document's DPI appears to be 3 times the screen DPI, and so Photoshop does the math and presents in what it thinks are physical units on screen.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful. Please feel free to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

100% depends on your screen, thats why it is impossible to adjust it to all screens. More about it here: [Life size image in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/life-size-image-in-photoshop)