# How to duplicate a group to a new document having this document the exact same size as the group?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using Photoshop CS3 and I have been given a quite big PSD with a lot of elements in it.
I want to select one of these groups in the layer pane and copy it to a new document, and this document needs to be the exact size of the group.

I have tried duplicating the group into a new document, but this results in a document with the same size as the original one.

I tried following this link [How do you create a new document from a layer group that's also the size of the group?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-create-a-new-document-from-a-layer-group-thats-also-the-size-of-the)
But I just can't control-c the layers I have selected?

My group is composed of text layer and one square layer with some effects in it (its a button).

Many thanks,
felipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate the group to a new document.

Then choose Image > Trim...

Tick the Transparent Pixels option and click OK.

The new document will be trimmed to remove all superflous areas.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hide all layers that you do not want to copy (the "eye" icon on the layers pane)
2. Ctrl A > Shift+Ctrl C > Ctrl N > Enter (or Apple/Command if Mac)
3. Go back to original document right click your group on the layers pane and duplicate it to the already existing document

Comment: For some reason I was getting an error when trying to Control C. And then I Shift+Control+C (copy merged) and it worked! Many thanks, Ryan

Comment: oh woops ya I should've said Shift+Ctrl+C because its on multiple layers.

Answer (score 0):

One other method I've used: Convert the group into a smart object. When you edit the smart object, it pops up in a new doc at the exact size of the group and you can save it out under a new file name. This is the fastest way I've found for pulling out bits and pieces of a PSD.

I'm sure you could script it or record an action if you have to do a lot of this.