# using the 'straighten' feature of PS to straighten just one layer not all of them?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

When i use the straighten of PS, i cant find a way to just get it to straighten one layer at a time, itseems to straighten the entire canvas, is there a way i can get it to work on just one layer ?

just to clarify by the straighten tool i mean draw a line with the ruler and then click straighten in the toolbar allong the top.

Im using cs5 but its a pretty common feature so im sure its similar in most versions.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests, locking the layers I didn't want to rotate, using the Arbitrary rotate in the image menu (which of course i knew already wouldn't do it). But it seem to be global operation no matter how you twist and turn it (pun intended).

It seems that the only way is to copy your layer to another image, do the rotation, then copy the layer back.

There are many ways to copy layers, here is one thread with some tips:
[How to copy layers from one Photoshop document to another?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/is-there-a-way-to-copy-layers-from-one-photoshop-document-to-another)